# How to convert in seconds from datetime to a timestamp?

Tags: java, python, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

Good day. Such a question - there is a method in python that gets datetime and converts it into a timestamp:

```
source = 'Friday 9:14 PM March 9 2018'
central_tz = pytz.timezone('Canada/Eastern')
utc_tz = pytz.timezone('UTC')

naive_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(source, "%A %I:%M %p %B %d %Y")
utc_ts = time.mktime(utc_dt.timetuple())
print(central_tz.localize(native_dt, is_dst=None))
print("naite_dt")
print(naive_dt)
central_dt = central_tz.localize(naive_dt, is_dst=None)
print("central_dt")
print(central_dt)
utc_dt = central_dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
print("utc_dt")
print(utc_dt)
utc_ts = time.mktime(utc_dt.timetuple())
print("utc_ts")
print(utc_ts)
```

On output:

```
naite_dt
2018-03-09 21:14:00
central_dt
2018-03-09 21:14:00-05:00
utc_dt
2018-03-10 02:14:00+00:00
utc_ts
1520640840.0
```

And I have implementation of the same method in java:

```
public static void scraper() throws ParseException {
        String source = "2018 марта 9, 09:14 PM";
        String pattern = "yyyy MMMM dd, KK:mm a";
        String central_tz = "Canada/Eastern";
        String utc_tz = "UTC";

        DateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        dt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(central_tz));

        Date date = dt.parse(source);
        String formatted = dt.format(date);
        System.out.println("Время по Канаде: " + formatted);

        dt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(utc_tz));
        formatted = dt.format(date);
        System.out.println("Время по UTC: " + formatted);

        Timestamp timestmp = Timestamp.from(date.toInstant());
        System.out.println("Время Timestamp: " + timestmp.toString());
        System.out.println("Время в секундах Timestamp: " + timestmp.getTime() / 1000);
    }
```

But it's output and it's true output:

```
Время по Канаде: 2018 марта 09, 09:14 PM
Время по UTC: 2018 марта 10, 02:14 AM
Время Timestamp: 2018-03-10 04:14:00.0
Время в секундах Timestamp: 1520648040
```

On final we have output timestamp in Python 1520640840 and output timestamp in Java 1520648040 - it's different!!! Why? And woh I can fixed it in Python? Thank's

Comment: They're off by exactly two hours. I'm willing to bet the Java one is a local time, and you're in a UTC+2 timezone (or a UTC+3 timezone that's in daylight saving time).

Comment: Speaking of timezones: you create a timezone for Eastern Canada and then call it `central_tz`? US/Canadian Central is an hour west of Eastern. That's pretty confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice the time shown in python is **2018-03-10 02:14:00+00:00** which you are using to convert into timestamp and in Java when you are using the date variable which has the time **2018-03-10 04:14:00.0.**

There's a 2 hour difference between both. Try to find why that happened. What I think is you are in timezon UTC +2 therefore the date variable stored the time as 4:14 am for which you did not set a time zone and in python your `date` variable "`utc_dt`" used for converting in timestamp has the timezone UTC hence its time is 2:14 am.

You can verify this by calculating the difference between both timestamps which is 7200 which means 2 hours. So in fact your Java time stamp is set according to your local time zone and python timestamp is set according to the  UTC time zone.